# Deleting spaces on multiple lines in VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

To indent HAML code I usually add or delete 2 spaces. Adding I do:

1. Enter visual mode ( ctrl + v)
2. jj to select the lines
3. shift + i to go into insert
4. type 2 spaces
5. ESC

That's it 2 spaces are added. However to remove the spaces, I't does not work, for example doing:

1. Enter visual mode ( ctrl + v)
2. jj to select the lines
3. shift + i to go into insert
4. Delete 2 spaces ( with backspace or delete)
5. ESC

This just does not work, other lines spaces are not deleted. How then can I do this ?

Here is an example code:

```
 .module_1
     .pricing_details
       %h2
         Save
```

The idea is moving everything so it matches 2 space in respecto .module_1 as:

```
 .module_1
   .pricing_details
     %h2
       Save
```

The propose solution using < > works only for indenting now I'd like to for example:

```
 .module_1
   .pricing_details
     %h2
       Save
```

move the above to:

```
 .module_1
 .pricing_details
   %h2
     Save
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> commands. You will need `:set shiftwidth=2` for them to work in this way.

---

**UPDATE**

Considering your last example, changing

```
.module_1
  .pricing_details
    %h2
      Save
```

to ⇓

```
.module_1
.pricing_details
  %h2
    Save
```

can be accomplished with moving to `.pricing_details` line and hitting `Vjj<`.

Comment: Yes works but if I repeat command multiple times it indents inner lines while not always removing indent on the top lines

Comment: @daniel Just use `Shift`+`V` for entering selection mode.

Comment: @daniel in your last example move to `.pricing_details` line, then press `Vjj<`.

Comment: This last Vjj< works exactly how I want it, thanks :), could you edit your answer and add this please.

Answer (score 4):

Highlight your text and do:

```
<
```

Use:

```
.
```

To repeat the action multiple times.  Note that this will shift the text whatever your shift width is.  If it is not 2, you can set it to 2 by doing:

```
:set sw=2
```

You can indent text the same way by using ">".

All of this is in the documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_25.html#25.3

Comment: This works on certain occations but is just not the same, doing this multiple times leads to the first line remaining the same while others are indented I'd rather insert and delete spaces

Comment: @Daniel ?? Just select the lines you want to shift properly!

Comment: @Daniel: Use "<".  It will 'unindent' it by 2 spaces if that is your shift width.

Answer (score -1):

in the vimrc:

```
" pressing F5 adds two spaces at beginning of line and goes to next line
inoremap <F5> <ESC>:s/\(.*\)/  \1/e<CR>:set nohlsearch<CR>ji
" also works when not in edit mode
map <F5> i<F5><ESC>

" F6 removes two spaces from the end of whitespace at the beginning of line
inoremap <F6> <ESC>:s/\(^\s*\)/\1/e<CR>:set nohlsearch<CR>ji
map <F6> i<F6><ESC>
```

To remove 2 spaces from the beginning of every line of a paragraph just press F5 through all its lines.

This is modeled after my keybindings for commenting and uncommenting C code (the difference is in the regex of course)

only drawback is it needs to disable search highlight since the regex matches damn near the entire document all the time.